# How to handle errors from the Read::read_to_end method?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am reading a file and parsing the data:

```
fn main() {
    parse_torrentfile("ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.torrent");
}

fn parse_file(filename: &'static str) {
    let mut f = File::open(&Path::new(filename)).unwrap();
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let file_content = f.read_to_end(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", file_content);
}
```

If `ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.torrent` is present, this works well, but if it isn't present, this error occurs:

```
 thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }'
```

How can I print "Not Exist File" or "process file parsing"?

Comment: Try `.expect("File doesn't exist")` instead of `.unwrap()`.

Comment: @ljedrz Thx, but it also `thread 'main' panicked at ' File doesn't exist: Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }', ../src/libcore/result.rs:799`, I wanna print only `File Doesn't exist`, is it not possible?

Comment: Read [*The Rust Programming Language* chapter on error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html). There's nothing special about this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be matching on the `Result` instead of calling `unwrap()` or `expect()`.  Once you've got the error, you can either print it out or look at the `ErrorKind` if you want to handle different errors differently.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    parse_file("doesnt_exist.txt");
}

fn parse_file(filename: &'static str) {
    let mut f = match File::open(&Path::new(filename)) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => {
            use std::io::ErrorKind::*;
            println!("Got error: {}", e);
            match e.kind() {
                NotFound => {
                    println!("File not found");
                }
                k => {
                    println!("Error: {:?}", k);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    };
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let file_content = f.read_to_end(&mut v);

    println!("{:?}", file_content);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9862b7105a9a02e2b40ac6c33030089&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: There's no need to specify the type of `v`.

Comment: No, but I don't see a problem with being explicit (it came from the question).

Comment: Remember that answers are not for **only** the OP. They are for *every person that finds this Q&A*. That's why I strive to make my answers as idiomatic as possible (or clearly indicate when they are not for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most idiomatic approach would be propagating the result outside `parse_file`, printing the error in `main`.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Error as IoError};
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    match parse_file("ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.torrent") {
        Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
        _ => {}
    }
}

fn parse_file(filename: &'static str) -> Result<(), IoError> {
    let mut f = File::open(&Path::new(filename))?;
    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let file_content = f.read_to_end(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", file_content);

    Ok(())
}
```

If you want to print the error in one line and then propagating it, you could do something like this instead:

```
fn main() {
    parse_file("ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.torrent");
}

fn parse_file(filename: &'static str) -> Result<(), IoError> {
    let mut f = File::open(&Path::new(filename)).map_err(|e| {
            println!("{}", e);
            e
        })?;

    let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let file_content = f.read_to_end(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", file_content);

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of non-idiomatic Rust in this answer. The `match` should be an `if let` if you only care about one branch. There's no need to specify the type for `v`. `map` and `map_err` shouldn't be used for side effects like printing values.

Comment: @Shepmaster When I said idiomatic, I was only talking about propagating the error, not the rest of the code whch I left almost untouched from the OP. Then it seemed to me that the OP was searching for a oneliner to get the job done, so I proposed the second solution (which is a bit ugly I know).

Comment: Remember that answers are not for **only** the OP. They are for *every person that finds this Q&A*. That's why I strive to make my answers as idiomatic as possible (or clearly indicate when they are not for whatever reason).

Comment: @Shepmaster Maybe you are right,but I prefer to not alienate posters rewriting half of their code, and give them a tons of answers to questions they didn't ask. I prefer to give a direct answer to only what OP asks. [There's another website for code view BTW]
I will keep in mind your observations though.